# Could I create a product with python?

Tags: shopware, shopware5

Is there a way to create a product on Shopware 5 with Python? If yes where is the documentation? I only found SW5s API doc but there is nothing regarding to further implementations. There is one entry for shopware on PyPi but the creator added no comment or description besides the publishing date on the readme.

As Python is the only language i know at the moment, and the only my last scripts i try to develop are in, i need to find a way to use the shopware API through Python. is there any way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

I am certain that python is capable of performing post requests. [Here](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/rest-api/api-resource-article/) you would find a reference on the article endpoint of Shopware 5. Unfortunately, due to a german translation error article === product in Shopware 5.

Comment: You mean it's `/api/products` instead of `/api/articles`  ?

Comment: No what I was trying to say is that article is a wrong translation of product. It's still the articles endpoint. Read the article and you know how to create a product/article.